# Accessing Swagger outside the Spring Boot Context path

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

My spring boot application have a contextPath like as shown below

```
server.contextPath=/api
```

I have added springfox swagger configuration and was able to get the swagger url from the given url like as shown below

```
http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html
```

Actually what I would want is to get the swagger ui outside the contextPath like as shown below

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

Like to know if this is possible or not.

Comment: then just remove *server.contextPath=/api* from property file

Comment: Thanks for the reply....I cannot remove contextPath of my application...any other way instead of removing contextPath

Comment: then why do you want to have application with any context path ?

Comment: The spring boot application already have api using this context path...and the client requirement was not to use the application context path for swagger ui

Comment: your question is not clear, you are saying, you will use swagger without using context path, but you won't remove context path. Then how do you think it can be done ?

Comment: @Ravi can we access swagger-ui.html without contextPath and all other api's using contextPath

Comment: It was already answered. But, I don't know what exactly you are expecting.

Comment: @Ravi its not resolved....can you please come for 2 min [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180187/discussion-between-alex-man-and-ravi)

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try it but maybe it can help you. If it's way to find out if swagger is running and when yes you can dynamically set

```
 System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/");
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

But as I said I didn't test and maybe this is stupid. Anyway I will try to test some solutions and I will write you

Comment: this is again removing the application contextPath

Comment: I mean something different. I will try it later and I write you :).